# Change Content.Load<Texture2D> format

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

We are developing some games in XNA that, thanks of Mono+MonoGame+MonoForAndroid, will be ready in all the three major mobile platforms.
The problem is that since we need to use as few memory as possible to avoid devices crashing, we chose to use texture format Bgra5551.

Unfortunatelly the content manager uses Color format for texture (A8R8G8B8) when you call Load method.

My question is: can I somehow obtain a 5551 texture using Content.Load ?

I already have the code that convert a 32bit texture to a 16bit texture. I was thinking to a way to override the Load method, but I didnt manage to find anything.

How could I ?

thank you very much,

-nicola marchesan

Comment: Code samples may help us give better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The default texture processor does not support that output texture format, but maybe you want create your own texture processor...

```
[ContentProcessor(DisplayName = "MyTextureProcessor")]
public class TextureContentProcessor : TextureProcessor
{
    public override TextureContent Process(TextureContent input, ContentProcessorContext context)
   {          
        TextureContent data = base.Process(input, context);

        // Convert data

        return data;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I found this http://konaju.com/?p=33 which explains well what you correctly suggested ;)